# How to change background colour in adapter list view in android?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, listadapter

In adapter listview first time click on listview of row, it is not working but second time it is working, the row background color is changed. Please suggest me how is working fine.

```
productList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        //mOnDoubleTapListener = listener;

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

            Log.d("Row", "Row:= "+row);
            Log.d("View", "View:= "+view);

            if(row != null) {
                row.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            }


            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);

            row = view;
            }});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use this way:-- This code will help to u for change the color of selected Item of listview**

Just take one variable Called SELECTED_POSITION=-1 in your activity;

When u clicked any item in ListView the position which is clicked that u will get by this code

```
productList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

            SELECTED_POSITION =position;
        }
     });
```

then implement Custom Adapter Class in which @override method is there is called getView(...)

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.row_adptr, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.adapterText1);
        holder.chkbox = (CheckBox) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        holder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        convertView.setTag(holder);          

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

       // this is the code when selected item stay at one position 
       if(position ==SELECTED_POSITION)
       {
            // set your selected Item Color
             convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
       }
        else
       {   // set your unselected Item Color
               convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
       } 

     ....Extra code of set value...
 }
```

Comment: did you forget to say `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` on OnItemClickListener?